# R sum values in a column but exclude lesser of specific values

Tags: r

I have the following data:

```
>str(Maximum)
num [1:6] 1.4  1.07  1.89  0.342  0.00  1.998
```

I want to sum all of these values but between the second and third, and fourth and fifth, only the greater value. So in this case I'm looking for 1.4 + 1.89 + 0.342 + 1.998. How would I go about doing this in R code?

Comment: Do you know the positions you want to exclude a-priori? (Ie, will the skipped values always be in those positions?) Or, is there a rule based on the values?

Comment: Skipped values will always be in those positions

Answer (score 4):

First element, plus maximum of (2,3) plus maximum of (4,5) + the 6th element.

```
maximum[1] + max(maximum[2:3]) + max(maximum[4:5]) + maximum[6]
```

Comment: Thank you! That works perfectly. How exactly does this sort command work? It just chooses the greater value between two assigned values?

Comment: Yes, the max(...) command will always return the value of the highest of the values within its brackets.

Answer (score 3):

If your vector `Maximum` always has 6 element, Florian's answer is the simplest way to do it. But if your vector is longer then you could do:

```
z1 = Maximum[seq(from = 2, to = length(Maximum)-1, by = 2)]
z2 = Maximum[seq(from = 3, to = length(Maximum)-1, by = 2)]
z3 = ifelse(z1>z2, z1, z2)
result = Maximum[1] + sum(z3) + Maximum[length(Maximum)]
```

For example:

```
Maximum = floor(runif(22, 1, 100))
> Maximum
 [1] 96  6  1 10 90 15 58 48 94 97 78 95 42 79 61 25 61 74 93 37 44 22
```

z1 would be the elements at even indexes (excluding ends):

```
> z1
 [1]  6 10 15 48 97 95 79 25 74 37
```

z2 the elements at odd indexes (excluding ends):

```
> z2
 [1]  1 90 58 94 78 42 61 61 93 44
```

and z3 the maximum value between z1 and z2 for each index:

```
> z3
 [1]  6 90 58 94 97 95 79 61 93 44
```

And then calculate the result by adding z3 and the start and end of `Maximum`

Note: the Maximum vector should have an even number of elements.

Answer (score 2):

You can specify the positions in a vector using `<vector.name>[<positions>]`.  Moreover, you can specify positions to skip using `-`.  Thus,

```
Maximum <- c(1.4, 1.07, 1.89, 0.342, 0.00, 1.998)
Maximum[-c(2,5)]
# [1] 1.400 1.890 0.342 1.998
sum( Maximum[-c(2,5)] )
# [1] 5.63
```

Answer (score 1):

A common method here is to use `tapply` to perform "group operations" and then aggregate the intermediate values.

```
vec <- c(1.4, 1.07, 1.89, 0.342, 0.00, 1.998)
group <- c(1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4)
```

Here, calculate the max of each group

```
 tapply(vec, group, max)
    1     2     3     4 
1.400 1.890 0.342 1.998
```

Then you can sum the resulting values

```
sum(tapply(vec, group, max))
[1] 5.63
```

One way to construct the group variable dynamically would be using `rep` a couple times like this.

```
reps <- c(1, rep(2, (length(vec) / 2) - 1), 1)
rep(seq_along(reps), reps)
[1] 1 2 2 3 3 4
```